# text validation on wizard droid

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, wizard

I am using Wizardroid to add items to my main list view, the wizard contains 3 "pages" where in each one i have multiple edittext fields.

i need to have text validation to the input since the fields cant be empty, therefore I used "addTextChangedListener". when the user enters text to the field it is being verified and I am calling "notifycomplete" to "release" the "next" button.

the main issue is when I am using this listener the keyboard automatically hidden after one character typed and then the edittext needs to regain focus to have the keyboard shown again.

when i am removing the code in the "addTextChangedListener" methods the keyboard stays up.

can someone propose for a proper validation check that will not cause the keyboard to be hidden or alternetevly a proper way to keep the keyboard up?

```
ed_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

     }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.length()>0)
        {
            notifyCompleted();
        }
        else {
            ed_name.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.wiz_empty_field_err));
            notifyIncomplete();
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I end up doing is use the wizardroid custom layout and by doing so gain control over the "next" button. upon click there is a validation of the text fields.